# $().html appends to shadow DOM instead of replace

Tags: jquery, shadow-dom

I have a page with one or more `<article>`s that each contain a `<nav>` and a `<section class='app-content'>` hosting a shadow DOM.  I want to programmatically load one of several templates to the `<section>` when a user clicks an element in the `<nav>`.

I have a helper function here, it should take the clicked child of `<nav>` and find the associated `<section>`, then either create or get a reference to the shadow DOM, clear the content, and insert the content of a template.

```
  //maps menu event to content container
  //loads one of several templates, replacing content
  function replaceShadowContent(nav_elem_clicked, content_to_load) {
    var $contentPane = $(nav_elem_clicked).parentsUntil('article').next();
    var shadowDOM;//$contentPane[0].shadowRoot;
    if (!!$contentPane[0].shadowRoot) {
      shadowDOM = $contentPane[0].shadowRoot;
    } else {
      console.log('make new shadow root');
      shadowDOM = $contentPane[0].createShadowRoot();
    }
    $(shadowDOM).html(document.importNode(document.getElementById(content_to_load).content, true));
  }
```

The templates, for now, just `<p>` elements.

The problem is, I end up with a list of `<p>`s in the shadow DOM rathar than just one at a time.  It behaves exactly the same if I use `.append()` instead of `.html()`.  I have tried doing it without jquery and only using normal DOM functions, I have tried various combinations of `.empty()`,`.replaceWith()`, etc.

I'm on the latest version of Chrome, using only jquery and the native API, no other libraries.

Here is a jsbin with the complete code: https://jsbin.com/fiwago/edit?html,output

Interestingly, this snippet from earlier in the day worked, but the console squawked that calling `createShadowRoot` was deprecated.

```
      var $contentPane = $(this).parentsUntil('article').next();
      var shadowDOM = $contentPane[0].createShadowRoot();
      shadowDOM.appendChild(document.importNode(document.getElementById('simple-widget').content, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working finally, by using native JS on `shadowDOM` rather than jquery.  I'm not sure exactly why this was happening, I assume its something internal to jquery that isn't exactly happy with shadow DOMs but I don't know.

Here is the working code:

```
  //maps menu event to content container
  //loads one of several templates, replacing content
  function replaceShadowContent(nav_elem_clicked, content_to_load) {
    var $contentPane = $(nav_elem_clicked).parentsUntil('article').next();
    var shadowDOM;//$contentPane[0].shadowRoot;
    if (!!$contentPane[0].shadowRoot) {
      shadowDOM = $contentPane[0].shadowRoot;
    } else {
      shadowDOM = $contentPane[0].createShadowRoot();
    }
    while (shadowDOM.firstChild) {
      shadowDOM.removeChild(shadowDOM.firstChild);
    }
    shadowDOM.appendChild(document.importNode(
        document.getElementById(content_to_load).content, true)
    );
  }
```

I had to use jquery to select the correct pane, but that's not applicable to the problem, and I switch to a regular DOM tree inside the `if` block.

The tricky thing was, when I tried simply `shadowDOM.removeChild(shadowDOM.firstChild)` it threw an exception: `firstChild` is undefined, can't remove.  For some reason, checking for `firstChild` in the loop fixes the problem, but the code never uses the loop, I threw a `console.log` in there and it never prints.  If you comment out the while loop, it appends without replacing each time.

I hope this spaghetti mess helps someone someday.

If anyone can explain the behavior, or confirm a bug let me know and I'll submit it.